# What typical percentage current is required to hold a standard non-latching reed relay/contactor shut?

Tags: relay, contactor

https://www.solarteam.nl/contactor-economizer has a nice description of a PWM approach to minimizing current consumption in a relay, once the relay is turned on. Presumably, and I might be wrong in my understanding, this is because to energize the relay the electromagnet needs to overcome the return spring force from a far distance but once it's closed the distance is much smaller and thus the electromagnet forces are higher.

Painting with a very broad brush, if a standard reed relay is spec'ed to go from normal to energized state at 100% current, what range of percentage current is required to keep the energized state?

Comment: Having read that article, I would find it simpler (in an application I'm currently involved in designing)  to test a suitable holding voltage and use an off-the-shelf switching regulator to provide that.  I have seen an application with 12V and 5V DC available, where 5V gave a reliable hold (unless you dropped the product but that would damage the optics).  Of course it depends on your drive circuit and whether you've got spare PWM capacity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no general rule of thumb, but many relay datasheets will tell you. Most relays will list a "must operate voltage", which is the lowest voltage that is guaranteed to actuate the relay (and a "must release voltage" which is the highest guaranteed to release the relay), but this isn't *quite* what you're looking for--this is the minimum voltage to close the relay, not the minimum to keep it closed.

[image: A relay datasheet showing the "must operate voltage" listed as "75% max"]
(from the [Omron G5Q series datasheet](https://components.omron.com/us-en/sites/components.omron.com.us/files/datasheet_pdf/J155-E1.pdf))

Some relays, especially large ones (where the coil needs a lot of power so the power savings of using an economizer like this might be significant) frequently list a "hold voltage", which is the lowest coil voltage at which a closed relay is guaranteed to remain closed. This is exactly what you want, but not all relays specify it.

[image: A relay datasheet showing the "holding voltage" as "0.4 Un" (Un being the nominal voltage)]
(from the [Finder 22 series datasheet](https://cdn.findernet.com/app/uploads/S22EN.pdf))

You can, if you want, individually characterize your relay with an adjustable power supply and a continuity checker. But you should probably add a decent bit of safety margin to numbers measured this way. You can't be certain that it won't need higher voltage at different temperatures, for instance.

Comment: That is indeed very helpful. Using the datasheet you posted, the must operate is 75% and the must release is a range from 5-34%, so this frames the economiser in the range from 34-75%. This points toward 50% current as a fair starting number for keeping those relays closed.

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit, and it looks like they newly posted relays operate at 40%. So very much the same ballpark. Thanks!

Comment: @KennSebesta You can't treat the "must release" voltage like that--if the must release is 5%, there's no guarantee that it *won't* release at even 50%--all that's guaranteed is that it *will* release at 5%.

Comment: This is something that varies from relay to relay, so don't treat this as a "40% is a safe number to use for any relay"--look for a relay that specifically specifies a holding voltage. 40% is only a good number to use for specifically a Finder 22-series contactor.

Comment: Understood and agreed. That's why I bracketed the must release and must operate, assuming the average between the worst case scenarios. The 50% lined up nicely with the 40%, and all that together helps bound that a relay needs ~25% of the energizing power to remain energized. This seems to be reasonably constant across the other relays I'm looking at. Thanks a lot for cluing me into the right way to search.

Comment: @fgrieu I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The number I gave there is in fact the minimum voltage that is guaranteed to close the relay, not a maximum by any means.

Comment: @fgrieu No, the "must release voltage" doesn't tell you anything about the voltage you have to apply to close it. Relays have hysteresis; causing a closed relay to open requires the voltage to go below a threshold that's lower than the one that causes an open relay to close. For instance, if you apply full coil voltage to close a hypothetical example relay and then change to 50% voltage, it will probably stay closed--but also, applying zero voltage to open it and then changing to 50% voltage will probably keep the relay open.

Comment: @fgrieu The mention of the must release voltage in that sentence is a parenthetical, and not related to the following clause. The must release voltage has absolutely nothing to do with closing the relay--only opening it.

Comment: @fgrieu If it's the wording as "close" that's confusing you, remember that "close" and "open" in electrical circuits has the opposite meaning to how they're used in plumbing and such--a closed relay allows current to flow, while an open one does not.

Comment: I misused close. OK let's forget about it, sorry. I'll remove my comments. Keep only one thing, that's a nice command.

Answer (score 9):

If you have high vibration environment, e.g. on a vehicle, you may need to go *higher* than the 100% current to ensure good contact in spite of vibration. Most relays are designed to safely dissipate a bit more power than rated.

Conversely, if you lower the holding current, you should qualify the relays on the application board per whatever vibration test your product will go through.

Some relay manufacturers have their vibration specs valid at "must operate" voltage, but some only test at rated coil voltage. Unless they are explicit in the datasheet about having tested at "must operate" voltage, you'll have to test yourself - or if you're a big customer, ask the manufacturer to do a custom test for you.

As an anecdote: I had seen a bench instrument that had to be installed in a small mobile event production van, and had to stay powered while the van was moving, often on roads where potholes were the norm rather than exception. All the relays inside (it had a dozen) had to be retrofitted with different models, as they didn't stay properly closed when exposed to vibration. The symptoms were as-if the contacts were electrically overloaded. The relays would fail with contacts welded closed.

Comment: I'm guessing the mechanism behind that failure mode could be that vibration separated the contacts enough to get some arcing, while the relay coil was holding them close enough together to not quench the arc.  So it actually did weld the contacts together!  (Or solder if the contacts were coated with something with a lower melting point.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You’re right!

Answer (score 3):

As well as vibration, consider that the link specifies that they control *current* (presumably in a closed-loop arrangement as with a stepper chopper drive).

If you control voltage (eg. open-loop PWM) you should take account of the tempco of copper which is +0.4%/K. Especially important in a high-temperature environment such as a vehicle. Some high temperature rated relays are not guaranteed to pull in even at full nominal voltage near their maximum coil insulation temperature rating, and drop-out would scale similarly. It's not hard to get 20-30% higher coil resistance at high operating temperatures. Relays operate from *current* but are typically specified in terms of voltage.